# How can i include a template from the parent theme in the current theme in Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento2

I'm using Magento ver. 2.1.8. I created a new theme and inherited the purchased theme. In the parent theme i have a template that i override in the child theme. How can i include the template from the parent theme in the current theme? I think that my decision is not optimal, but i think it's a dirty solution to copy all template HTML from the parent theme.
My solution is:

```
$templateFile = str_replace('my-theme-vendor/my-theme', 'parent_theme_vendor/parent_theme', $block->getTemplateFile());

include($templateFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add it to you theme by copying it.

**Foo/Bar** is child theme. Its parent is **Precious/Theme**

copy
**Precious/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml**
to
**Foo/Bar/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml**

An you have your template ready to be edited. This is a cleanest way to override your parent theme template.